# change strings in file python

Tags: python, string, file

Could you explain why does it work in that way?
I have a file and I need to add in the same file  at the end of each string  some info, which depends on values in the  same position in string. I'd tried many variants but it works only when I read all lines put them in variable and then write in file. Is this only way to solve my case. Why my second code doesn't work in the right way (it only add info in the last line)?
Or maybe it could be easier solution without adding file content in variable and not to use additional RAM to keep all massive of file strings
Sorry for the long message)

work

```
with open(finalfile, 'r+') as file:
    content = file.readlines()
with open(finalfile, 'r+') as file:
    for line in content:
        if (line.split(sep='|')[2]) == "" or line.split(sep='|')[3] == "":
            newline = str(line.rstrip()) + "|||\n"
            
        else:
            newline = (str(line.rstrip()) + "|" + districtdict[(line.split(sep='|')[2])] + "|" + streetdict[(line.split(sep='|')[3])]).rstrip()+"|\n"
            
        file.write(newline)
```

doesnt work

```
with open(finalfile, 'r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        if (line.split(sep='|')[2]) == "" or line.split(sep='|')[3] == "":
            newline = str(line.rstrip()) + "|||\n"
            
        else:
            newline = (str(line.rstrip()) + "|" + districtdict[(line.split(sep='|')[2])] + "|" + streetdict[(line.split(sep='|')[3])]).rstrip()+"|\n"
            
        file.write(newline)
```

Comment: "Lines" don't _really_ exist in text files, they're basically a continuous series of characters some of which happen to be `\n`. So an in-place "add to each line" isn't possible, as this means moving every subsequent character (and therefore every subsequent "line") accordingly.

Comment: A better and safer approach if you do not want to load everything in RAM would be to write to a temporary file, then to replace the old file with the temporary one when you're done. This is what most text editors are doing.

Comment: @mozway I'm not really sure that's the right duplicate. This really needs to get cleaned up somehow.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I added some more options, this has been covered in several QAs already

Comment: @mozway I agree that it's well covered. But as long as these sorts of questions are frequently asked, Python curators should come to a consensus about canonicals for this sort of issue.